# How to handle events for dynamically generated controls?

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, dynamic, controls

I am trying to generate a number of buttons on form load event. For this i am using a button array. I want each of those buttons to have a click event handler. I've searched almost everywhere but can't seem to find a clear solution. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 Private Sub Home_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim tableLayoutPanel = New System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel()
    tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = 5
    tableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 1

    Dim BtnArray(5) As Button

    For i As Integer = 0 To BtnArray.Length-1

        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 20))
        tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100))

        tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(BtnArray(i), i, 0)
    Next
    GroupBox1.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel)
End Sub
```

Comment: The question is how to HANDLE the events, not how to RAISE them.  The events are raised in the same way as always: clicking the `Buttons`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code,It will solve your problem

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
                           MyBase.Load
    Dim tableLayoutPanel = New System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel()
    tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = 5
    tableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 1
    Dim BtnArray(5) As Button
    For i As Integer = 0 To BtnArray.Length - 1
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(New 
          System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 20))
        tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(New 
           System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100))
        BtnArray(i) = New Button
        BtnArray(i).Name = "Button" + i.ToString
        AddHandler BtnArray(i).Click, AddressOf Button_Click
        tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(BtnArray(i), i, 0)
    Next
    GroupBox1.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel)
 End Sub

'Event which is call when button is click
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    MsgBox(sender.name)
End Sub
```